# Unitronics OPC Server -> JIException Access denied

Tags: java, opc

I try to connect to an OPC Server of Unitronics I installed on my Computer. But no matter what I try I just cant figure out how to connect to it. I am working with utgard, openscada, jinterop and I am very new to this topic.
If I use another OPC Client like PowerOPC browser or kassl opc client there is no problem to connect.

```
JISession session=JISession.createSession("localhost","<mycomputeradmin>","<myadminpw>");

serverList=new ServerList ( session, "localhost");
```

The problem is that I get an JIException Access denied, but my login information should be correct:
org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: Access is denied, please check whether the [domain-username-password] are correct. Also, if not already done please check the GETTING STARTED and FAQ sections in readme.htm. They provide information on how to correctly configure the Windows machine for DCOM access, so as to avoid such exceptions.  `[0x00000005]`

Answer (score 1):

After a long time I finally found a different library dealing with OPC. **JEasyOPC**
I am using this now and it works very fine and it is easy to set up.